# what is wrong with my code

Tags: algorithm2e

what is wrong with my code please do not closed my topic

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
   \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
   \usepackage{algorithmic}
   \begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]}{
    \caption{Algorithm Gaussian elimination with patrial pivoting}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \For{$i=1:1:n$}{
            $p_{i} = i;$
        }        

    \For{$k=1:1:n$}{
        }
        {
        }
        $max=|a_{pk}k|$\\
        \For{$i\;=k+1:1:n$}{
           \If{$max=|a_{pk}k|$}{$l= i;$\\$max = |a_{pk}k|$}
            }
            {
            }
             $r=pl;$\\
             $pl = pk$\\
             $pk = r;$        
              \For{$i=k+1:1:n$}{
              {
              {
                  $a_{pi}k = a_{pi}ka_{pk}k;$
              }
              {
              }  
              {
              } 
                \For{$j=k+1:1:n$}{

                  $a_{pi}k = a_{pi}ka_{pk}k;$


              }
       }      
      }
    } 
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

i can solved it.

Comment: What is wrong? No `\documentclass`. No loading of packages. No `\begin{document}`. No `\end{algorithm}`. No `\end{document}`. Once you fix the obvious things you will be much more likely to get help on the less obvious ones.

Comment: ok sry for that i fix it now the error is he dont print it the correct line in the algorithm i  have try to remove and replace the  something in the code put he did not resovled . i do not now what doing  wrong the wrong is in the line \for loop  i think :( Sry i do not kno what doing to solved

Comment: please resolve the previews code t look good i do not know what are doing to do looks good  in my first post .

Comment: It still has no `\documentclass`. (However, I did not downvote.) In order to mark code as code you have to indent the lines.

Comment: i have put in my code document class what do you mean document class?

Comment: No, there is no `\documentclass`. Please read [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/194703) carefully and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better-formatted version of your code that compiles. What you need to understand between the differences:

- Use `\;` for line-endings. It prints a `;`. If you don't want the semi-colon, add `\DontPrintSemicolon` to your preamble.
- Don't add unnecessary blocks `{`...`}` within your code if it doesn't do anything.
- Fundamentally the problem lies with you having an opening/closing brace after `\begin{algorithm}[H]`. Remove it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \For{$i=1:1:n$}{
    $p_i = i;$
  }
  \For{$k = 1 : 1 : n$}{
  }
  $max=|a_{pk} k|$\;
  \For{$i = k + 1 : 1 : n$}{
    \If{$max=|a_{pk} k|$}{
      $l = i$\;
      $max = |a_{pk} k|$
    }
  }
  $r = pl$\;
  $pl = pk$\;
  $pk = r$\;        
  \For{$i = k + 1 : 1 : n$}{
    $a_{pi} k = a_{pi} k a_{pk} k$\;
  }
  \For{$j = k + 1 : 1 : n$}{

    $a_{pi} k = a_{pi}k a_{pk} k$\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

On a mathematical note, `$max$` denotes `m` × `a` × `x`. You might be better off using `$\mathrm{max}$`.

Comment: i UDNERSTAMD THE ERROR AMD I RESOLVE :)